# Intuitive reason that the regular representation is a uniform function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory, deligne-lusztig-theory

Corollary 12.14 of Digne-Michel's book *Representations of finite groups of Lie type* gives various decompositions of the regular representation $\operatorname{reg}_G$ in terms of the Deligne-Lusztig characters. The two I am primarily interested in are $$\operatorname{reg}_G = \frac{1}{|G^F|_p} \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}} \epsilon_G \epsilon_T R^G_T(\operatorname{reg}_T) = \frac{1}{|G^F|_p} \sum_{\substack{T \in \mathcal{T}\\ \theta \in \operatorname{Irr}(T^F)}} \epsilon_G \epsilon_T R^G_T(\theta).$$

My question is: can someone give an intuitive reason for why these decompositions exist? I am not asking for a proof, but for a moral reason that this *should be true*.

For context: the Deligne-Lusztig characters form a core part of my thesis on the representation theory of finite groups of Lie type, but I do not have the space to completely develop all of the results. I have therefore chosen a few proofs which I feel to be illustrative of the techniques in the field, and for the rest I am trying to offer an intuitive explanation. If I had to guess a decomposition of the regular representation then this would certainly be it (possibly modulo the signs), but I am having difficulty coming up with a way to justify this to readers.

An example of the type of argument I am looking for: the Mackey decomposition for Deligne-Lusztig induction/restriction can be interpreted as `pushing forward' the Bruhat decomposition of a finite group of Lie type onto its representations. Indeed, you can make this argument rigorous (at least on the level of characters, I'm not focusing on the actual representations) by looking at the action of $G^F$ on a certain finite affine variety related to the double cosets, then using properties of the Lefschetz number to make combinatorial simplifications, so to me this gives a good intuition for the Mackey decomposition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but the kind of geometric or structural intuition your are looking for may not exist. To put it another way, the reason behind the fact in the OP is a non-trivial combination of several other central facts, but can't conceptually be reduced to either of them.

If we want to guess that some virtual character such as
$$ \frac{1}{\lvert G^F\rvert_p} \sum_{T, \theta} \epsilon_G \epsilon_T R^G_T(\theta)$$
equals the regular character $\operatorname{reg}_G$, then, as a first step, we had better make sure that they have the same degree. That this is true is non-trivial and the proof actually uses some of the same steps as the proof that the two characters are equal. More precisely, to compute the degree of the above character, one has to, as far as we know, at some point use the fact that *the Steinberg character $\mathrm{St}$ is zero on all non-semisimple elements*. This is based on properties of Bruhat decomposition/BN-pairs and Curtis's alternating sum formula for $\mathrm{St}$.

The above fact about the values of $\mathrm{St}$ together with the fact that values of $\sum_{\theta} R^G_T(\theta)$ are Lefschetz numbers and hence zero on non-trivial semisimple elements, gives an easy expression for the inner product of $\mathrm{St}$ and $\sum_{\theta} R^G_T(\theta)$. The alternating sum formula for $\mathrm{St}$ together with the fact that $\mathrm{St}(1)=|G^F|_p$, can then be used to show that
$$\sum_{\theta} \epsilon_G \epsilon_T R^G_T(\theta)(1) = \frac{|G^F|}{\lvert G^F\rvert_p}.$$
Finally, a non-trivial result of Steinberg says that there are $|G^F|_p^2$ $F$-stable maximal tori, so $\sum_{T,\theta} \epsilon_G \epsilon_T R^G_T(\theta)$ indeed has degree $|G^F|$.

One might ask whether lifting the question to isomorphism of representations or some other categorified objects would make the fact in the OP more 'geometric'. It is not clear to me that this can be done and the fact about the values of the character $\mathrm{St}$ highlighted above is used in all of the proofs I know of the statement in the OP. Note that the proof of 12.14 in Digne--Michel uses this fact (when it refers to 9.4), so in particular I am not aware of any character-free proof (as in, does not use anything about character values).

In summary, I think the result in the OP can be made plausible by combining the observation in LSpice's answer with a summary of why the two characters have the same degree (e.g., as given above), but this doesn't reduce the result to any straightforward conceptual or geometric principle. Instead, like many non-trivial proofs, it is a combination of several main ingredients. In this case the main ingredients are the existence and properties of the Steinberg character (the alternating sum formula, character values), Bruhat decomposition, the character formula for Deligne--Lusztig characters, etc.

Comment: Wow, I definitely wouldn't have expected such an accumulation of subtle facts to be involved in a simple-looking formula!  Thank you for this very nice exposition.

Comment: All of the answers so far have been great, but I think this one hits closest to the mark in terms of the context I was looking for. Thanks to everyone for their interesting suggestions.

Comment: Since both your answer and [@user148212's](https://mathoverflow.net/a/402564) use the Steinberg, I wonder if I could ask as a follow-up:  is there any reason that one should expect *a priori* the Steinberg to intervene in the proof of the asserted equality?

Comment: @LSpice Yes. When trying relating Deligne--Lusztig char with a particular usual char (e.g. in this case the reg), it is a natural desire to take a look at Steinberg, because of the tensor product property R_T(\theta)\otimes St= Ind_T^G\theta. (Studying tensor products with Steinberg is itself an important topic; for example, some works (around 2010!) of Hiss--Zalesski are all about it.)

Comment: @LSpice If 'a priori' means that we already know that $\mathrm{St}$ is irreducible and non-zero precisely at non-semisimple elements, then one can expect it to play a role at least in the degree computation in my answer, given that $\sum_{\theta}R_T(\theta)$ is zero at non-identity semisimple elements. This is the only place where it seems necessary to use $\mathrm{St}$. One also needs the character formula for $R_T(\theta)$ at *semisimple* elements, and this is equivalent to the formula in user148212's comment above, but it is not necessary to use $\mathrm{St}$ for this.

Comment: But that every $G^F$ has an *irreducible* character whose values are zero precisely at the non-semisimple elements, that is something that I think could not have been expected before the definition of the Steinberg character. It is a serendipitous and (to me) mysterious fact whose analogue in more general situations such as $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{Z}/p^r)$, $r>1$, does not hold.

Comment: @AStasinski May I ask where this proof came from? I find it interesting that Digne-Michel actually derives the number of rational maximal tori from this decomposition (Corollary 12.15) rather than using it in the proof.

Comment: @Martin Skilleter It's probably in Deligne--Lusztig or some early follow-up paper by Lusztig.

Answer (score 5):

I think the two equalities are the same, since $\operatorname{reg}_T$ equals $\sum_\theta \theta$; so I'll focus on the equality
$$\operatorname{reg}_G = \frac{1}{\lvert G^F\rvert_p} \sum_{T, \theta} \epsilon_G \epsilon_T R^G_T(\theta).$$
Let's call the virtual character on the right $\rho_G$.

I don't know if this counts as intuition or only as a crude proof sketch, but, [at least for me](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363226/each-mathematician-has-only-a-few-tricks/363238#363238), the fundamental fact in harmonic analysis is that the integral of a non-trivial character of a group is $0$.  From this point of view, when I evaluate $\rho_G$ at an element $g = s u$, I get (up to constants)
$$
\sum_{T, \theta} \epsilon_G\epsilon_T\sum_{g s g^{-1} \in T} \theta(g s g^{-1})Q_{g^{-1}T g}^{G_s}(u)
= \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{T \subseteq g G_s g^{-1}} \epsilon_G\epsilon_T Q_{g^{-1}T g}^{G_s}(u)\sum_\theta \theta(g s g^{-1})
= 0
= \operatorname{reg}_G(s u)
$$
unless $s = 1$.  That, of course, doesn't tell you what happens on the unipotent set—and, even if you knew that you also had vanishing on (the complement of $1$ in) the unipotent set, it wouldn't tell you which multiple of the regular representation you've recovered—but at least this makes it plausible that some equality like the one you propose holds.

(If that's too much computation, maybe "Fubini + Abelian harmonic analysis" is a pithier way of saying it.)

Comment: By the way, since my background is in harmonic analysis on $p$-adic groups, I can't resist mentioning that the signs $\epsilon_G$ are also important there, except that we need to account for the fact that we no longer have that $G$ is quasi-split; so we now need to look at $(-1)^{\operatorname{rank}(G) - \operatorname{rank}(G^*)}$, where $G^*$ is the quasi-split inner form of $G$.  This quantity is called the Kottwitz sign of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the argument of this formula in Digne--Michel's book can be viewed as a process unpacking properties (of duality functors and Deligne--Lusztig inductions) around the probably more fundamental formula
$$(*)\quad \mathrm{St}_G=\sum_{P_I} (-1)^{|I|}\mathrm{Ind}_{P_I^F}^{G^F}1,$$
where $\mathrm{St}_G$ is the Steinberg character. (Note that, Digne--Michel's book uses this formula to define the Steinberg character, however, this is not how initially it was defined; more details on the history can be found in [this survery](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-16/issue-2/The-Steinberg-representation/bams/1183553833.full) of Humphreys.) Then an important middle step from $(*)$ to the regular char formula is to realise that (see 12.13, and 12.8, in Digne--Michel)
$$\sum_{P_I} (-1)^{|I|}\mathrm{Ind}_{P_I^F}^{G^F}1=\frac{1}{|W|}\sum_T\epsilon_T\epsilon_GR_T^G(1).$$
In the below, instead of the original formula, I will focus on $(*)$ which admits a very nice geometric explanation:

Every finite group of Lie type is equipped with a geometric/combinatorial construction called spherical building, which admits a simplicial complex structure, hence a chain complex
$$C_n\rightarrow C_{n-1}\rightarrow...\rightarrow C_0;$$
for example, in the case of type $\mathsf{A}$, the highest simplexes correspond to the complete flags and the lower simplexes correspond to partial flags. The original finite group of Lie type then acts on the cycles/boundaries/homologies etc. Now the Hopf trace formula tells you that one can use the alternating sum of the characters of the group actions on $C_r$ (which turns out to be the parabolic induction from the trivial character) to obtain the alternating sum of the characters on the homology groups.

On the other hand, the building is (topologically) a bouquet of equidimensional spheres; in particular, its integral homology is zero except the $0$-th-degree and the highest degree, and the highest degree part turns out to be $\mathrm{St}_G$ by the Hopf formula. This gives a geometric explanation of the formula $(*)$!

To track the details of this story, you may search the names Curtis and Solomon--Tits. A very nice book containing all these stuffs is Ronan's *Lectures on buildings*

**Remark.** Another fantastic aspect of the above picture is it suggests that the sign character of the Weyl group should be viewed as an analogue of the Steinberg character. Indeed, there is a subcomplex of the building called a Coxeter complex, and doing the above process for this subcomplex gives a similar formula for the sign character.

Comment: I don't know how the Steinberg was originally defined for finite groups of Lie type, or by whom, but, in the context of $p$-adic groups—which of course is not the context here!—it was defined (by Harish-Chandra, of course) as exactly the alternating sum you mention.

Comment: I am confused by this argument.  You refer to $R_T(\operatorname{id})$; should that be $R_T(\operatorname{reg})$?  Is the equality you assert with the Steinberg on one side and these $R_T(\operatorname{id})$ on the other side obvious?  How does it establish the desired equality?

Comment: @LSpice It was originally defined by Steinberg... The alternating sum expression, I believe, was first discovered by Curtis. In the equality I mean $R_T(id)$, not $R_{T}(Reg)$ (it follows from 12.13 in Digne--Michel). I will edit to add more details.

Comment: What does $R_T(\operatorname{id})$ mean, though?  I'm used to $R_T$ taking a complex representation as input.  I just noticed that you also use $\operatorname{id}$ in the definition of the Steinberg, which I am more used to seeing with the trivial character, so I'm even more confused.

Comment: (And of course Steinberg as its discoverer was a safe, but because of [Stigler's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy) not a foregone, guess, so I wasn't sure.  :-) )

Comment: Also, there does not appear to be a 12.13 in Digne–Michel, at least if that means the 2nd edition of _Representations of finite groups of Lie type_.

Comment: @LSpice It means the trivial character (I don't know why I used that notation!)... now changes.

Comment: @LSpice I was refererring to the first edition of Digne--Michel; for the 2nd edition it should be 10.2.5.