# Generalization of the geometric series representation of the Kronecker delta for arbitrary lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms

In [On construction of holomorphic cusp forms of half integral weight](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-58/issue-none/On-construction-of-holomorphic-cusp-forms-of-half-integral-weight/nmj/1118795445.full) by Shintani, in the last equation of page 96, an identity for the Kronecker delta for elements of $L^*/L$ is defined. Here, $L$ is an integral lattice and $L^*$ is its dual.

The identity can be written as follows:
\begin{equation} 
    \lvert\det Q\rvert^{-1}\sum_{h''\in L^*/L }e^{2\pi i Q(h-h',h'')}
    =\delta_{h,h'}\;,
\end{equation}
where $Q$ is a quadratic form defined on $L$.

I understand that this is a generalization of the geometric series representation of the Kronecker delta. How does one prove this identity?

Answer (score 1):

If $h'=h$, then for each $h''\in L^*$ one has $\exp(2\pi iQ(h-h',h''))=1$, so your sum is equal to
$$
|\det Q|^{-1} |L^*/L|=1.
$$
On the other hand, if $h\neq h'$, then there is an element $h_0\in L^*/L$ such that
$$
\exp(2\pi iQ(h-h',h_0))\neq 1.
$$
Denote this number on the left by $a$. Now, let
$$
S=\sum_{h''\in L^*/L} \exp(2\pi i Q(h-h',h'')).
$$
Change the variable of summation a bit: each $h''$ is uniquely represented as $h'''+h_0$, where $h'''\in L^*/L$. Hence
$$
S=\sum_{h''\in L^*/L} \exp(2\pi i Q(h-h',h''))=\sum_{h'''\in L^*/L} \exp(2\pi i Q(h-h',h'''+h_0))=a\sum_{h'''\in L^*/L} \exp(2\pi i Q(h-h',h'''))=aS.
$$
Therefore, $S=0$, as needed.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding your explanation, a two-point explanation of what's going on is (1) the sum of the values of a non-trivial character of a finite group is $0$ (my [favourite trick](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363238)), and (2) fixing one argument of a quadratic form gives a bilinear form.

Answer (score 0):

The approach [indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425343) by @AlexanderKalmynin is a good heuristic, for sure.

Still, there is a somewhat larger context that may be more explanatory, depending on one's tastes.

Namely, we can see that we are talking about Fourier expansions of *Dirac* *combs*, that is, sums of Dirac deltas over a lattice $L$ in some $\mathbb R^n$. Then it's not exactly that the value *on* the lattice is $1$ (in a Kronecker delta sense), but that it's $0$ pointwise *off* the lattice. Maybe $+\infty$ *on* the lattice, but that's not exactly right, either. Being pointwise $0$ off the lattice is entirely correct.

For simplicity taking $L=\mathbb Z^n$, the naïve way to write a Fourier expansion for the periodic Dirac delta, the Dirac comb $u$, is correct:
$$
u \;=\; \sum_{\xi\in \mathbb Z^n} 1\cdot \psi_\xi
$$
where $\psi_\xi(x)=e^{2\pi i\langle x,\xi\rangle}$. A reason to not write this as a *pointwise* equality (with argument $x$, etc.) is that it does not converge pointwise at all. It *does* converge very well in a Sobolev space $H^{-{n\over 2}+\epsilon}$, for every $\epsilon>0$. Probably it's not worth going into the details of this, so much as just letting on the key words, and noting that there definitely *is* a way to make this as rigorous as one wants.

But, again, the rigor has some cost… and if we have a good heuristic (that somehow we *know* to be good), that's possibly even better! :)